# What's the meaning of "[...] steady tryna pick it up like a call."?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm from Brazil and my native language is Portuguese.
I study English listening to songs, watching TV, movies and series and, sometimes, it appears some difficulties. I'm not very familiar with slang, figures of speech, etc.

Anyway, I'd like to know what this phrase means:
"And I ain't gonna give it up, **steady tryna pick it up like a call**."

Comment: Lady Gaga lyrics are NOT a source you should be using to learn English.  Most, yea, almost all English speakers don't know what the hell she's saying here.  Then again, who am I to talk?  When I moved to Portugal, aside from talking to people on the street, I learned Portuguese by watching telenovelas and reading comic books.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Obrigado mesmo assim pela ajuda! :-)

Comment: Não ha de que.  Foi um prazer.

Comment: *Steady* is probably *(in)stead I('m)*.

Comment: Mr. Harman is too kind. :-) I'm no wizard of lyrics, but my guess is that The Lady is eliding several syllables and is singing a shortened version of, "steady, try not to pick it up like a [cell phone] call." Hopefully, someone 50 years younger than I will correct me if I'm wrong. Best of luck in your study of English, Rebecca! :-)

Answer (score 1):

"tryna" might be "[I'm] trying to".  That's not slang -- just colloquial pronunciation.  The "o" of "to" is unstressed, so it is reduced to schwa, which is heard and spelled as "a", because unstressed "a" is also reduced to schwa.

Final "ng" is often "n'", then the preceding vowel "i" is nasalized, the "n" is lost before the voiceless stop "t", the "t" becomes a flap, and finally that flap is nasalized by the preceding nasal vowel.  "n" is what English speakers hear and write for nasal flap.